# Error installing OCI8 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: upgrade, php, 14.04, oracle

I've just upgraded my VM to Ubuntu 14.04, and my OCI8 PHP driver has stopped working.

I've tried to install/upgrade it, but it doesn't work. That's the error messages I get:

```
marc@sf2:/build/buildd/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download$ sudo pecl install oci8
downloading oci8-2.0.8.tgz ...
Starting to download oci8-2.0.8.tgz (190,854 bytes)
.........................................done: 190,854 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "/build/buildd/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download/oci8-2.0.8.tgz"
Download of "pecl/oci8" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/oci8"
Download failed
install failed
```

I've "untared" the file oci8-2.0.8.tgz without problems and the package.xml is there... What can I do to fix this? Must I revert to Ubuntu 13.10? Because I need oci8 for my job to be done...

Thanks for your help!

*EDIT:*
I've found the problem: PECL isn't working on Ubuntu 14.04 and OCI8 must be installed from source or using a phar package. I'm still looking for information about how to install it.

*EDIT 2:*
I've found it!

1. Download and extract the `oci8` library from PECL repository (http://pecl.php.net/package/oci8)
2. Run the `phpize` command to create the build scripts
3. With the InstantClient installed, run `./configure -with-oci8=shared,instantclient,$ORACLE_HOME`
4. Finally, run a `make install` and `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

All this information is taken from the PHP OCI8 Installation Guide (http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php)

Comment: this guy have another solution:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/457242/download-of-pecl-xdebug-succeeded-but-it-is-not-a-valid-package-archive
so i tryed pecl install -Z oci8 and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mHouses, you are my hero.
I spent 4 hours yesterday trying to install pecl_http-1.7.6 on my 32 bit ubuntu 14.04 with no avail.
Your instructions worked perfect for me, too.

all I had to do was changing your

```
"./configure -with-oci8=shared,instantclient,$ORACLE_HOME"
```

to a simple

```
"./configure"
```

Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge

Answer (score -1):

Latest PHP version has them built-in but installation of these extensions from `pecl` is mostly failed.

Best way is **compile & install the extensions from PHP source**

See my blog on this problem for more detail: http://itblog.study.land/how-to-install-php5-pdo_oci-oci8-and-other-extensions-for-ubuntu/

Comment: Link to your blog is broken... Please, try to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, my blog has been move here: http://itblog.study.land/how-to-install-php5-pdo_oci-oci8-and-other-extensions-for-ubuntu/