# Download of "pecl/xdebug" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive

Tags: 14.04, php, xdebug

I tried to install the `xdebug` in Ubuntu 14.04, but when I execute the following command:

```
sudo pecl install xdebug
```

it returns the error:

```
Download of "pecl/xdebug" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
```

Someone had the same problem or knows how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: The solution > sudo pecl install -Z xdebug worked for me, too. But it does not solve the problem, it only works around it. The issue shows up elsewhere in the system, PHP is not playing well with archives either. Any solution?

Answer (score 13):

The bug is somewhere in the pecl uncompressing module for Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit. Try this:

> sudo pecl install -Z xdebug

-Z makes pecl download an uncompressed version of the package. Works for me.